# Gson in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, gson

I'm developing Flutter app using bluetooth.I'm reading some characteristic values in native platform then I'm sending them to Flutter on EventChannel

```
            DeviceInfo deviceInfo = new DeviceInfo(deviceData, value);
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            String json;
            json = gson.toJson(deviceInfo);
            Log.d("GetDeviceInformation", gson.toJson(deviceInfo));
            deviceInformation.success(json);
```

During the debug testing everything was working perfectly. When I build release version of the app the only results that I'm getting is empty map {}. The deviceInfo variable is fine. My only track is that it could be something related to Gson and release version of the app. What are your ideas?

Comment: Are you using ProGuard or a similar obfuscation and 'shrinking' tool? If so you probably have to configure it to keep all fields of your model class as they are. (see existing questions here on StackOverflow about this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Marcono1234's answer pointed me in the right direction.
Added following code to app/build.gradle:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
        // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug

        minifyEnabled true
        useProguard true

        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

And following proguard rules to app/proguard-rules.pro:

```
-keep class com.example.** { *; }

#Flutter Wrapper
-keep class io.flutter.app.** { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.plugin.**  { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.util.**  { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.view.**  { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.**  { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.plugins.**  { *; }

##---------------Begin: proguard configuration for Gson  ----------
# Gson uses generic type information stored in a class file when working with fields. Proguard
# removes such information by default, so configure it to keep all of it.
-keepattributes Signature

# For using GSON @Expose annotation
-keepattributes *Annotation*

# Gson specific classes
-dontwarn sun.misc.**
#-keep class com.google.gson.stream.** { *; }

# Application classes that will be serialized/deserialized over Gson
-keep class com.google.gson.examples.android.model.** { <fields>; }

# Prevent proguard from stripping interface information from TypeAdapter, TypeAdapterFactory,
# JsonSerializer, JsonDeserializer instances (so they can be used in @JsonAdapter)
-keep class * extends com.google.gson.TypeAdapter
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.TypeAdapterFactory
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonSerializer
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer

# Prevent R8 from leaving Data object members always null
-keepclassmembers,allowobfuscation class * {
  @com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName <fields>;
}

# Retain generic signatures of TypeToken and its subclasses with R8 version 3.0 and higher.
-keep,allowobfuscation,allowshrinking class com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken
-keep,allowobfuscation,allowshrinking class * extends com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken

##---------------End: proguard configuration for Gson  ----------
```